# I need to convert string into hash in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery

```
"{'long_island_sound' => 'Long Island sound','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '210','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '211','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '370','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '372'}"
```

I have this string, I want to convert this into hash in Jquery/Javascript.

```
{'long_island_sound' => 'Long Island sound','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '210','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '211','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '370','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '372'}
```

Is there anyway Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the [parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) function in jquery

```
    var myLoc="{'long_island_sound' => 'Long Island sound','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '210','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '211','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '370','primary_btm_or_ee_' => '372'}"
    myLoc=jQuery.parseJSON(myLoc)
```

If you having object notations then try

```
myLoc=jQuery.parseJSON(myLoc.replace(/&quot;/gi,"\"").replace(/\[/gi,"").replace(/\]/gi,"").split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for your conversion,but really dont know what you are looking for.

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    var hash = 0, i, char;
    if (this.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        char  = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
};
```

Comment: This is for prototype javascript but I am using jquery.